# Is there an integration between Spring Batch and Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-stream

My project has a lot of Spring Batch Jobs.
I have requirement to create externalized configuration for message brokers (example Kafka, rabbitMQ etc.).
I want to use spring cloud stream since it has various binders to solve this problem.
Hence i wanted to understand if there is an integration between the two frameworks, please explain.

Comment: There is an integration between the two, but please elaborate on your requirement to guide you in the right direction. What, specifically, are you trying to achieve? Can you explain your requirement without referring to Spring Batch or SCS?

Comment: My requirement is to process a series of steps, each step can have multiple sources (Kafka, rabbit MQ, Rest API, file ) to read the data from and also multiple destinations to write the data into. The read and write should happen in batches. I want to know which framework can achieve this ?